# Is mutex ownership handed off strictly only to threads which have requested for the lock prior to unlocking?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Situation:

1. Thread 1 currently owns the mutex.
2. While Thread 1 retains ownership of the mutex, Thread 2 makes a request for the same lock.
3. Thread 1 unlocks the lock.

At this juncture can another thread (say, Thread 3) swoop in and make a request for the lock and acquire it (as shown below)? Or does POSIX guarantee that a mutex shall be acquired by a thread that is already waiting for the said mutex at the moment of unlocking a mutex?

[image: MUTEX_acquisition_race]

The man page for `pthread_mutex_unlock()` states that -

> If there are threads blocked on the mutex object referenced by mutex
>   when pthread_mutex_unlock() is called, resulting in the mutex becoming
>   available, the scheduling policy shall determine which thread shall
>   acquire the mutex.

This seems to say that Thread 3 can not swoop in and acquire the mutex, though I am not fully assured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment of the unlock all threads that were trying to lock the mutex change state from BLOCKED to READY. A specific implementation may make sure that only one of those threads will get the mutex, but at that point in time any thread may try and lock the mutex.

So Thread 3 may be able to swoop-in and get the mutex before anyone else in some implementations (or maybe even in all of them).

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the treads will be granted locks in the order they requested them.

Comment: I wasn't asking if lock acquisition is on a FCFS basis. In the scenario `LOCK(m, t1) -> ACQUIRE(m, t1) -> LOCK(m, t2) -> LOCK(m, t3) -> UNLOCK(m, t1) -> LOCK(m, t4)`. At `UNLOCK(m, t1)` there definitely can be contention between t2 and t3 (i.e. may not be FCFS). My question was, is t4 too contending for the lock (t4 made the lock request **after** 'm' was unlocked)?

Comment: There are a lot of things involved, process scheduling mechanisms, particular mutex management implementation etc. If we ignore all this, and there were no ACQUIRE after UNLOCK(m, t1), it would be logical to assume that LOCK(m, t4) will compete for the mutex. With this said, I'm curious, what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Not so much as trying to solve a problem as trying to understand how POSIX mutexes and threads are expected to behave.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such guarantee.

The situation can only arise when Thread 1's unlock is racing with Thread 3's lock, and in that situation there's really no difference between the lock coming slightly before the unlock or slightly after it.

Comment: Are you sure? I ask because in the case of pthread_cond_signal() and pthread_cond_wait() there was some confusion about this *swoop in* problem. David Butenhof clarifies that pthread_cond_signal() only wakes up threads that called pthread_cond_wait() before the signal.
http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=609

Comment: In the case of pthread_mutex_unlock() the way I interpreted the man page was that the same behaviour is to be expected here too i.e. pthread_mutex_unlock() tries to unblock threads already waiting on it (first), i.e. "atomic unblock".

Comment: The difference here is that for the case of `pthread_cond_signal()` called while holding the mutex associated with the condition variable, the unblock and wait are ordered by the lock - so it becomes meaningful to talk about whether the wait happened before or after the signal.  That's not the case in your example - there's no imposed ordering constraint between the thread 1 unlock and the thread 3 lock.  (Although perhaps you could create such a constraint by using a second mutex).

Comment: I would point out that you don't even need a third thread - you can have Thread 1 try to re-lock the mutex again, and in fact if you do that you can trivially observe the same thread able to unlock and relock the mutex thousands of times while another thread is blocked waiting for it.

Comment: No, the discussion in the link I provided speaks simply about pthread_cond_signal() irrespective of whether it is called under the aegis of a lock or not. If you read towards the end of that discussion (*geoffclare*) you will see the updated language of the pthread_cond_signal() man page. Pasted below -

Comment: `The pthread_cond_broadcast() and pthread_cond_signal() functions shall atomically determine which threads, if any, are blocked on the specified condition variable cond. This determination shall occur at an unspecified time during the pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() call.  The pthread_cond_broadcast() function shall then unblock all of these threads. The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of these threads.`

Comment: Yes, but if you read through the discussion you'll see that it only matters in the case where the signal is called under the lock, because that point at which the list of waiting threads is atomically determined is otherwise not ordered with respect to threads putting themselves on the waiting list.  If there's no ordering between two events A and B then it is not a well-formed question to ask what is guaranteed if A happens before B.